# Ionic header and subheader not rendering the same in browser and simulator

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am having header and subheader in my app. I have created html that looks like this:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
    <a ui-sref="main.logout" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon">
    </a>
    <a class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-search">
    </a>
    <a class="button button-icon icon ion-person">
    </a>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-subheader bar-dark">
    <a href="#">Populært
    </a>
    <a href="#">Siste
    </a>
  </ion-header-bar>
```

And when I am testing the app in the browser (chrome) it looks almost as I want it to look, but when I use emulator for ios, header and subheader appear bigger than what they should.

This is the screenshot from browser:

[image]

And this is the screenshot taken from emulator:

[image]

This is my scss file for this page:

```
.bar.bar-dark{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 45px;
    padding-top:0;
    background-color: $dark-background-color;
    color:$light;
    border-color: $dark-background-color;
    background-image: none;

    .row{
        padding-top:0;

        .icon{
            font-size: 2rem;
        }
        .ion-navicon{
            font-size: 3rem;
        }
        .right{
            padding-top:16px;
        }
    }

    a{
        color:$light;
        text-decoration: none;

        &:active{
            color:$gray;
        }
    }
}

.bar-subheader {
    top: 45px;
}

.has-subheader {
    top: 90px;
}

.item-light {
    .article{
        img{
          width: 100%;
        }

        h1 {
            color: $light;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 5rem;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 2rem;
            padding: 0 10%;
        }
    }
    .row{
        padding:.7rem;

        a{
            font-size: 1.1rem;

            i {
              vertical-align: middle;
              font-size: 2.1rem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my scss file for all pages:

```
body{
    background-color: $dark-background-color;
}

.item {
    border: 0;
}

.item-content {
    padding:0!important;
}

.right{
    text-align: right;
}

//Buttons
.button{
    min-height: 60px;

        &:active, &:hover{
            border-color:transparent;
        }
}

//Customizing Ionic Icons
.icon{
    color:white;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.ion-ios-heart-outline, .ion-ios-heart {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color: $red;
}

.ion-ios-chatbubble, .ion-chevron-right {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color: $gray;
}

.ion-chevron-left {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: $light;
    margin: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    z-index:1;
}

.ion-social-facebook {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: $gray;
}

.popup-head {
  background-color : $dark-background-color;
  border: 0;

  .popup-title {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

**Updated code**

I have changed the classes to different names in hope to override the default bar-header class. This is my css:

```
.articles-header {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top:0;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: $dark-background-color;
    color:$light;
    border-color: $dark-background-color;
    background-image: none;

    a{
        color:$light;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 3rem;

        &:active{
            color:$gray;
        }
    }

    .right-icons {
      float: right;
    }
}

.articles-subheader {
    top: 45px;

    a {
      font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .button:hover {
      color:$light;
    }
}

.has-subheader {
    top: 90px;
}
```

And this is my html:

```
<div class="row articles-header">
    <a ui-sref="main.logout" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon-round">
    </a>
    <div class="right-icons">
      <a class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-search-strong">
      </a>
      <a class="button button-icon icon ion-person">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row articles-subheader articles-header">
    <a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="ShowHideBulletpoint('siste')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="bulletpointSiste"></i> Siste
    </a>
    <a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="ShowHideBulletpoint()"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="bulletpointPopular"></i> Populært
    </a>
  </div>
```

But it finally worked well with suggestion by Tomislav. What I want know is if I was to change the height now, should I change it in the css Tomislav wrote, and to this values are just used to override but not actually change the height or should I change the height in my articles-header, articles-subheader classes?

Comment: Can you add your code in fiddle? @Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ionic uses platform detection to decide how tall the header should be.
>   So, to override it, you need to use the entire correct CSS selector.

```
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-header:not(.bar-subheader) {
  height: 64px; }
  .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-header:not(.bar-subheader).item-input-inset .item-input-wrapper {
    margin-top: 19px !important; }
  .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-header:not(.bar-subheader) > * {
    margin-top: 20px; }
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .tabs-top > .tabs, .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .tabs.tabs-top {
  top: 64px; }
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .has-header, .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-subheader {
  top: 64px; }
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .has-subheader {
  top: 108px; }
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .has-tabs-top {
  top: 113px; }
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .has-header.has-subheader.has-tabs-top {
  top: 157px; }
.platform-ios.platform-cordova.status-bar-hide {
  margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

Comment: I haven't used not selector before, as I read it is used to give every other element other than selected a value, so do this values like height in your code actually have an effect on height, or do they just override it. What I mean to ask is do I need to change the actual height of the bar here or write down separately where I already have it in my css file. I have edited the question to make it more clear. Btw, this has override it and it actually looks good now on emulator! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in your `ion-content` add `class = "has-subheader"`i hope this can solve your problem

Comment: have you tried to see emulator in browser like `ionic serve -l`

Comment: when I do that, it looks like it should look

Comment: not sure how to add all .scss files since I have few so I put together main .scss file and the one that is used specifically for this page, it is not looking as it should be, but at least you can see the code  https://jsfiddle.net/21fxyemj/